# on suse11 executables are run using sh instead of bash. How to change this

Tags: bash, opensuse

On Suse 11 though the default shell is bash, when I run any executable shell like ./IsCurrentShell then this script is run using sh instead of bash. How can I make this behavior to change such that the scripts run using ./ should run with bash.

EDIT :- Looking for global level solutions like any changes in .bashrc or any environment variable change. Or adding entry to some config file.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `#!/bin/bash` to the shebang line of your script explicitly should help.